# How can I write this list symbol in Latex?

Tags: symbols, lists

I am still a beginner to LaTeX, and I would like to know how to write this list (3 exclamation marks are in a square).

[image]

Comment: Re-welcome to the TeX.SE. community....:-)...I suggest enumitem package.

Answer (score 2):

Here there is a minimal working example using `\fbox` with `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{itemize}[label={\fbox{!!!}}]
    \item alpha
    \item beta
\end{itemize}
 \lipsum[41][1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `itemize` would be better than `enumerate`

Comment: @egreg "Comandi Comandante" :-)..I accept the suggestion :-))))